# Is it explained anywhere how the Nine tails biju was kept in control by all its jinchuriki?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, it is shown that Gaara’s One tail used to frequently take control and rampage the Sand village. Similarly, in Shippuden, it is shown that the Eight tails also used to go on rampage till Bee masters the tailed beast transformation.

How was it that the Nine tails only went on rampage when it was controlled by Obito? It is understandable that Hashirama maintained control as long as he was alive. But how did his wife and Kushina manage to control the beast when they were the jinchuriki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashirama's wife, Mito and Kushina both belonged to the Uzumaki clan. It's as Kabuto said, the Uzumaki had life forces “as tenacious as a cockroach's”, because they were able to survive situations which would otherwise prove fatal for other people: Having a large amount of chakra was never what the Uzumaki were known for. They were always revered for their vitality.

The Uzumaki were also extremely skilled in sealing jutsu. In fact it was Kushina who taught Minato about fuinjutsu(along with Jiraya). All this enabled the Uzumaki to behave as the perfect Jinchurikis.